# Confusion about AWS AutoScaling and AMI role in it

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

I know how to AutoScale. Now I need to know how to configure a web server so that I can add it to ELB and make it trigger AutoScaling (up and down).

I have an EC2 server running a web server. I have mounted an EBS and am using it as the web root. Now I want to make an AMI based on this server and tell AutoScaling to launch new servers based on this AMI.

Everyday my Wordpress site gets updated with new posts. If I make the AMI today and after two days I have a traffic spike that causes the ELB to scale up to meet demand, how will my EBS data be updated on the AMI?

I want to understand the role of the AMI in AutoScaling. How will the newly launched server in the scaling group have the `www` data that is on the attached EBS. I know that an EBS volume can only be attached to one server.

Also, when the AMI is used to launch a new server, will it grab the latest data from the source server and update the AMI at the moment it is launched so that the new server will have the most recent changes.

Can someone guide me through this?

Comment: In order to use autoscaling, your instances need to use shared nothing architecture. Wordpress is not configured like this by default.

Comment: And on the contrary, AWS recommends using EBS for persistent Data. @Rohan Zakie, post this question on AWS forum to get inputs from Amazonians.

Comment: so what whould be the good walkthrough for wordpress autoscaling

Comment: This question is probably a better candidate for http://serverfault.com/.

A standard Wordpress installation assumes one physical server with both the web server and database server running locally. Adding a second physical server to host the database is fairly easy. If you have a high traffic site you should consider doing that anyway.

As soon as you start autoscaling the web server your complexity jumps up pretty high. I would suggest doing some more research.

Google for these keywords: `aws autoscaling wordpress`.

Also consider the Wordpress forums: http://wordpress.org/support/